# Susy column layout reordering

Tags: css, sass, grid-layout, susy-compass

I have the following content that I would link to style and reorder with Susy.

The source order is the following and may not be changed.

```
<div class="item a">A</div>
<div class="item b">B</div>
<div class="item c">C</div>
<div class="item d">D</div>
```

The required layout is:

```
   -------------------------------
   |   A   |      B      |   C   |
   |-------|             |       |
   |   D   |             |       |
    ------------------------------
```

or:

```
   -------------------------------
   |   A   |      B      |   C   |
   |-------|             |       |
   |   D   |             |       |
   |       |             ---------
   |       |             |
   ---------             |
           |             |
           ---------------
```

or:

```
   -------------------------------
   |   A   |      B      |   C   |
   |       |             |       |
   |       |-------------|       |
   |       |             ---------
   ---------
   |   D   |
   ---------
```

and so on.

Basically the column D should follow the flow of the column A.
How can I accomplish that with Susy?

I've come up with the following [prototype](http://sassmeister.com/gist/90000d26a0cf26d5308a) which works with only text in the columns.

```
$susy: (
  columns: 4,
);

.item {
  background: lightgray;
  outline: 1px solid;
}

.a {
  @include span(1);
}

.b {
  @include span(2 at 1 isolate); /* Why do I place this at 1 and not at 2? */
}

.c {
  @include span(last 1);
}

.d {
  width: span(1);
}
```

This approach breaks down when I want to use `div`s with `clear: both` inside column D, as in the following case.

```
<div class="item a">A</div>
<div class="item b">B</div>
<div class="item c">C</div>
<div class="item d">
    <div style="clear: both">Title</div>
    Other text
</div>
```

In this case, the column D is placed correctly on the left side of the layout, but below A, B and C.

Answer (score 0):

```
@include span(2 at 1 isolate);
```

This means put `b`, after `width of 1 span` with `width of 2 span`. Span width is calculated according to `columns` parameter at `$susy` (`total_width/4` in your case)

If your a, c, d has width of 1 unit and b has 2, this is perfectly correct.

Comment: As you can see from the layout sketched above, B spans 2 columns.

Comment: According to the documentation: for isolation, you can use either an arbitrary width or a column index (starting with 1).
"at 1" means "at position 1" and not "after width of 1 span", or?

Comment: I did read it, but probably I did not understand it, can you point me where it says that `@include span(2 at 1 isolate);` means `put after width of 1 span`?

Answer (score 0):

The following is the solution I could find. I basically used a wrapper around B and C to push both of them to the right.

```
<div class="item a">A</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="item b">B</div>
    <div class="item c">C</div>
</div>
<div class="item d">
    <div style="clear: both">Title</div>
    Other text
</div>
```

This align the two columns on the right side.

```
$susy: (
  columns: 4,
);

.item {
  background: lightgray;
  outline: 1px solid;
}

.wrapper {
  @include span(last 3);
}

.a {
  @include span(1);
}

.b {
  @include span(2 of 3);
}

.c {
  @include span(last 1 of 3);
}

.d {
  @include span(1);
  clear: left;
}
```